# Setting multiple attributes of a Ruby object in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class with bunch of attributes (`first`, `second`, `third`, etc.).
I need to go through all "even" attributes (i.e. `second`, `fourth`, `sixth`, etc.) and make some corrections to just those:

```
report.first = Calculate('1')

report.second = Calculate('2')
report.second *= 0.9 if requireCorrection && report.second > 5

report.third = Calculate('3')

report.fourth = Calculate('4')
report.fourth *= 0.9 if requireCorrection && report.fourth > 5

report.fifth = Calculate('5')

report.sixth = Calculate('6')
report.sixth *= 0.9 if requireCorrection && report.sixth > 5

# etc.
```

As you can see, I have the exact same code for each "even" attribute, except for the different attribute name. Is there a way to avoid this repetition in the code (I have around 50 attributes in total)?

Comment: What is `Calculate`?

Comment: More importantly, what is your real goal? You might not need such a construct at all.

Comment: What does this have to do with pass-by-reference? I notice that you accepted an answer which has nothing to do with pass-by-reference.

Comment: @JörgWMittag typical Ruby behaviour does not allow to pass object to function, but solution were provided - solve this task.

Comment: "typical Ruby behaviour does not allow to pass object to function" – What do you mean? That's pretty much the only thing you *can* do in Ruby.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Ruby never pass reference of object, it's always pass copy, and if you have couple of objects that you want to modified with exact function (not class method) you cant do it just writing correct function.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. What do you mean by "correct function"? What do you mean by "exact function"? What do you mean by "class method"? Ruby doesn't have class methods (every method is an instance method), and Ruby doesn't have functions (all executable code is either a method, a block, a module definition, or a script). Also, Ruby *always* passes the reference of an object. What it does *not* do, is pass an object by reference.

Comment: Ruby never passes reference of an object. to prove it just try:

`def double_var (x)
      x *= 2   
    end
  a = 2
  double_var(a)
  puts "a = #{a}"`
a still equal 2!, Ruby always passes values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object#send` to invoke an arbitrary method on `report` by specifying the method name as a string or a symbol:

```
def make_correction(report, which_method)
  current_value = report.send(which_method)
  current_value *= 0.9 if current_value > 5
  report.send "#{which_method}=", current_value
end
```

The method names `first`, `second`, `third`, etc. do not easily lend themselves to automatization, but if you renamed the methods to `item_1`, `item_2`, etc., you could use a loop to process all of them:

```
(1..50).each do |i|
  report.send "item_#{i}=", Calculate(i.to_s)

  if i.even?
    make_correction(report, "item_#{i}") if require_correction
  end
end
```

If the method names need to stay the same, you can still simplify the code like this:

```
attrs = [:first, :second, :third, :fourth, :fifth]

attrs.each_with_index do |attr, ix|
  i = ix + 1  # indexes are zero based, we need to adjust them

  report.send "#{attr}=", Calculate(i.to_s)

  if i.even?
    make_correction(report, attr) if require_correction
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that exactly that I searched for!